# Cloud firestore version 0.14.3 is causing version conflits in flutter mobile app

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

versions:

```
  firebase_core: ^0.5.3
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.10.1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.4
```

**I integrated 0.14.3 of cloud firestore which gave me error that "change core firebase version to 0.5.3 from 0.4.0" after i downgraded core firebase then it conflicted with firebase auth. **

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the old version of cloud firestore as the new version is **cloud_functions 0.7.2**. Firebase went through some breaking changes in recent times so I suggest you use the latest versions of all the packages to avoid any conflict. Instead of downgrading, you should upgrade all of your packages to the latest version.

Comment: i have tried upgrading all but it didn't work

Comment: could you please show the complete error which you are facing?